# Plot certain points only

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot trading signal buy snd hold as follow:

```
!pip install yfinance
import yfinance as yf

# Data 
df=yf.download('^GSPC',start='2009-11-26',end='2014-12-31',interval='1d')

# generate signal 
df["SMA-25"]=df['Close'].rolling(25).mean()
df['SMA-diff']=df["SMA-25"].diff()
df['prediction-signal']= [1 if df.loc[ei,'SMA-diff'] > 0 else 0 for ei in df.index ]
df['yesterday-signal']= df['prediction-signal'].shift(1)

df['Sell']=[df.loc[ei,'Close'] if (df.loc[ei,'prediction-signal']==0 ) &( df.loc[ei,'yesterday-signal']==1) else 0 for ei in df.index ]
df['Buy']= [df.loc[ei,'Close']  if (df.loc[ei,'prediction-signal']==1) & (df.loc[ei,'yesterday-signal']==0) else 0 for ei in df.index ]
# I did the following but it also plotted 0 which made the graph funny 
plt.plot(df['Close'],color='b',linestyle='-')
plt.plot(df['Buy'],color='g',linestyle='None',marker='*')
plt.plot(df['Sell'],color='r',linestyle='None',marker='*')
```

Any insights would be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `0` values with `None`. Datapoints with value `None` will not be drawn.

There are two ways to get `None` instead of `0`:

- in the two lines where you create the columns for `Buy` and `Sell`, you can replace the `0` in the `else` branch with `None`:

```python
df['Sell']=[df.loc[ei,'Close'] if (df.loc[ei,'prediction-signal']==0 ) &( df.loc[ei,'yesterday-signal']==1) else None for ei in df.index ]
df['Buy']= [df.loc[ei,'Close']  if (df.loc[ei,'prediction-signal']==1) & (df.loc[ei,'yesterday-signal']==0) else None for ei in df.index ]
```

- if you do not want to change your calculation logic, you can replace the values afterwards just before plotting:

```python
df.replace({0: None}, inplace=True)
plt.plot(...
```